# pass the model value to @Html.CheckBoxFor on click function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass the model value to  @Html.CheckBoxFor on click function

This is my code

```
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.itemCategoryList[i].addItem, new { @onclick = "showImages(Model.itemCategoryList[i].ItemID)" })
```

But it is getting Javascript error and it says,
Model is not define.
So how to solve it?

Comment: Show your javascript. But you will be far better using unobtrusive javascript rather that putting behavior in your markup

Comment: Show us how was the HTML generated on DOM.

Answer (score 5):

`Model.itemCategoryList[i].ItemID` is your MVC model, you need to format it correctly in your code. You can use `string.Format` to do this. Change

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.itemCategoryList[i].addItem, new { @onclick = "showImages(Model.itemCategoryList[i].ItemID)" })
```

to

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.itemCategoryList[i].addItem, new { onclick = string.Format("showImages({0})", Model.itemCategoryList[i].ItemID) })
```

That will force the code to be evaluated

Comment: When I added it it saya " illegal character"

Answer (score 1):

Just add single quotes around brackets eg '{0}' tat would convert it to string and wont give illegal character error

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.itemCategoryList[i].addItem, new { onclick = string.Format("showImages('{0}')", Model.itemCategoryList[i].ItemID) })
```